# Downloading Data From .txt file containing URLs with Python again

Tags: python, curl, pycharm, dump, lynx

I am currently trying to extract the raw data from a .txt file of 10 urls, and put the raw data from each line(URL) in the .txt file. And then repeat the process with the processed data(the raw data from the same original .txt file stripped of the html) by using Python.

```
import commands
import os
import json

# RAW DATA
input = open('uri.txt', 'r')
t_1 = open('command', 'w')
counter_1 = 0

for line in input:
    counter_1 += 1
if counter_1 < 11:
    filename = str(counter_1)
    print str(line)
filename= str(count)
command ='curl ' + '"' + str(line).rstrip('\n') + '"'+ '> ./rawData/' + filename

output_1 = commands.getoutput(command)
input.close()

# PROCESSED DATA
counter_2 = 0
input = open('uri.txt','r')
t_2 = open('command','w')
for line in input:
    counter_2 += 1
    if counter_2 <11:
      filename = str(counter_2) + '-processed'
      command = 'lynx -dump -force_html ' + '"'+ str(line).rstrip('\n') + '"'+'> ./processedData/' + filename
    print command
output_2 = commands.getoutput(command)
input.close()
```

I am attempting to do all of this with one script. Can anyone help me refine my code so I can run it? it should loop through the code completely once for each kind line in the .txt file. For example, I should have 1 raw & 1 processed .txt file for every url line in my .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Break your code up into functions. Currently the code is hard to read and debug. Make a function called `get_raw()` and a function called `get_processed()`. Then for your main loop, you can do

```
for line in file:
    get_raw(line)
    get_processed(line)
```

Or something similar. Also you should avoid using 'magic numbers' like `counter<11`. Why is it 11? Is it the number of the lines in the file? If it is you can get the number of lines with `len()`.

Comment: there are 10 lines in the file. I was thinking it would begin counting from 1, 2,...10. I meant to put 10.

Comment: My point is, if you hard code the value, then you'll never be able to process a file with a different number of lines. You should see how many lines are in and use that as the number of iterations.

Comment: I only need to do this once with one document that I know how many lines are in it. I understand where you are coming from.